# How to add work item to commit in new git experience interface in new Visual Studio 2019

Tags: git, ide, visual-studio-2019, workitem

Quick Question for Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.8.3, How do you connect the work item to the commit in the new git changes tab? I am having a really hard time using this new git experience thing. I can see my work item in team explorer but no idea how to add this work item to the commit in this new interface. Usually, there will be a button to add related work items when committing the files in the previous version. Please someone help me out?

Comment: it look like you can just use hashtag '#' in commit message, but the work items is commit message. I don't want work item in my commit message

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> it look like you can just use hashtag '#' in commit message,

That is the recommended syntax.
Example:

```
Fix a bug #1234
```

That would [actually close the work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/devops/repos/git/resolution-mentions?view=azure-devops)

See more at "[Drive Git development from a work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/connect-work-items-to-git-dev-ops?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Frepos%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Frepos%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops)"
You can link a work item to commits but also other objects:

> The link types you can add within the development section are Branch, Build, Changeset, Commit, Found in build, Integrated in build, Pull Request, and Versioned Item.

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/devops/boards/queries/media/link-tracking-artifact-to-artifact-link-types.png?view=azure-devops]

Comment: thanks a million, will read more on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could also turn of the preview of the new Git features.
TOOLS=> OPTIONS => search for preview => checkbox

[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkQce.png)

If you like the preview feel free to keep using it of course.
Personally I'm not really digging it.

[MSblogPostAndReasons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkQce.png)

Comment: I already tried that, it seems like microsoft plans to go with this changes and every visual studio update will change the setting back to this new git feature

Comment: Yea but at least I'm seeing a lot of feedback on their post. Let's hope it get's improved for the better in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the option to turn off the awful "new git experience" is gone from VS2022. And there is still no option to add a DevOps work item like you could in the Team Explorer.

Another example of M$oft not listening to their users.